# Find $f ' (0)$ for the function $f(x) = g(x)/x^2$ when $x\not = 0$ and $ f(x)=0$ for $x=0$

Tags: calculus

Find $f '(0)$ for the function
\begin{align} 
f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{g(x)}{x^2},  & \text{if }x \not = 0\\
  0, & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases} 
\end{align}

With
\begin{align}
g(0)=g'(0) = g''(0) = 0 \\
g'''(0) = 14
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Think of $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

Comment: Nice hint - my you've grown an impressive beard :-) +1!

Comment: Hello, dear friend! I hope to cross paths soon! +1

Comment: @Amzoti: He is Gandalf. Gandalf is a character and you know him if you see the movie called Hoobit!

Comment: @BabakS.: Yes, I actually like him as he has excellent wisdom, street smarts and knows just how much to help! The video comes out soon of the latest movie. Hope all is well and good to see you around as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Use the definition and L'Hôpital's rule.

The answer is $\dfrac pq$ with $p,p-q\in\{7,1,8,6,4\}$.

Comment: Are you going to change the numbers if your reputation increases ;) ? Or is 7186 a coincident ?

Comment: @macydanim :) Actually is for user71864. I didn't see the connection with my reputation. Further hint: If my reputation increase to 7194 I will change it yes.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the user ID matches the numbers as well. Scary!

Comment: @macydanim: Do you know the [strong law of small numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers)?

Comment: No I didn't know that. Thanks for that. Though 7186 isn't that small ;)